# need to disable jquery on click

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following html code

```
<div class='login'><a href='#'>Log in</a> to create custom dashboard</div>
```

This is my jquery code

```
$(".login").click(function() {
    $(this).children('a').removeAttr("href");
    $(this).attr('class','disabledlogin');
    ..............
}
```

So when I click on "Log in" link the dialog appears and I need to disable "Log in" link. But even if I change the class attribute I'm able to click and open another login dialog. What is the problem?

Comment: use jQuery.unbind() to unbind click event from your link :)

Comment: Is your jQuery wrapped in a document.ready call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.unbind()` to unbind the event handler.

```
$(".login").click(function() {
    $(this).children('a').removeAttr("href");
    $(this).attr('class','disabledlogin');

    // unbind the click handler. it should no longer fire.
    $(this).unbind('click');
});
```

To revert, i.e. to add back the handler, you need to separate the handler into a function and bind it when needed using `$(".login").click(onLinkClick);`

```
function onLinkClick() {
    $(this).children('a').removeAttr("href");
    $(this).attr('class','disabledlogin');

    // unbind the click handler. it should no longer fire.
    $(this).unbind('click');
}

// call this initially for binding first time
// call this whenever you need to revert
$(".login").click(onLinkClick);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. Can you suggest how to revert this change, if the user close login dialog. After closing I have to reload the page to be able to open it again.

Answer (score -2):

Use @techfoobar suggestion:

```
$(".login").click(function() {
    $(this).children('a').removeAttr("href");
    $(this).attr('class','disabledlogin');

    // unbind the click handler. it should no longer fire.
    $(this).unbind('click');
}
```

Comment: Your use of .`on()` would affect every click and not unbind after the first.

Comment: @j08691 as the element will be disabled, it will not make any difference.

Comment: Did you try it? I also don't recall divs having a disabled attribute.

Comment: Ups, you're right. Saw badly the element, thought it was a submit button or similar. Gonna change.